# PHP Regex matching paragraph break

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
This is some test I want to keep\n
\n
**Header**  \n
Some test text \n
Another test  \n
Something else  \n
\n
 - bullet point i want to keep
 - this bulleted list could be another paragraph or header, etc.
```

What I'm trying to do is come up with a regex that'll match...

```
**Header**  \n
Some test text \n
Another test  \n
Something else  \n
\n
```

...so that I can strip out that segment of contents.  It's safe for me to identify this by the header text, in this case `Header`, but I can't assume the ending is a bulleted list, it could be anything, so I was planning to end the match by 2 newlines.

I've been trying to find a regex that'll do what I need, `\*\*Header\*\*(?:.+?)(?:\r*\n){2,}` seems to, but I can't get it to match - see https://regex101.com/r/1OUgAV/1/.

Feels like I'm missing something silly here, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the text there is `\n` literally instead of a newline. But the pattern that you tried will only match if the text also ends with 2 newlines. It will [not match](https://regex101.com/r/uiDYZW/1) when the text ends after `Something else`

You don't need the `s` modifier to make the dot match a newline. Instead you could match all the lines asserting that at the start of the line, what follows is not a newline.

If you want to match only the header part, you could use

```
\*\*Header\*\*.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\*\*Header\*\*` Match `**Header**`
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\r?\n).*` Assert what is directly to the right is not another newline. Then match the whole line.
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI2muY/1)